# Phonegap Update Error

Tags: cordova

I can not update phonegap version. I am trying to update version using below command.

> npm update -g phonegap

But it gives me error which is shown in below image. I have tried to solve it but still stuck to update. Please guide me how to do it. [image]

Comment: As per logs... npm is not able to connect to github.com.. Please make sure github.com is accessible in your system. If you are behind corporate proxy, Please set proxy in npm as well

Comment: Thanks Rupesh, I have already checked it. I can install phonegap version 3.2 but not able to install or update phonegap version 3.5. I dont know why its not allowing to install latest version.